# Converting the integer representation of a word back to a String

Tags: java, integer, append, tostring

This is a homework assignment and I'm having trouble with my output.  Everything works as expected except the Integer.toString() isn't giving me the result I want.  It is still outputting just a bunch of numbers when I want them to be converted to the actual word.  Here's the code and output:

```
    import java.io.*;

    public class NumStream extends OutputStream
    {
        public void write(int c) throws IOException
        {  
            StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
            switch(c)
            {
                case ' ': sb.append(" ");
                    break;
                case '1': sb.append("One");
                    break;
                case '2': sb.append("Two");
                    break;
                case '3': sb.append("Three");
                    break;
                case '4': sb.append("Four");
                    break;                
                case '5': sb.append("Five");
                    break; 
                case '6': sb.append("Six");
                    break;
                case '7': sb.append("Seven");
                    break;
                case '8': sb.append("Eight");
                    break;     
                case '9': sb.append("Nine");
                    break; 
                case '0': sb.append("Zero");
                    break;
                default:  sb.append(Integer.toString(c));
                    break;
            }
            System.out.print(sb);
        }
        public static void main(String[] args) 
        {
            NumStream ns = new NumStream();
            PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(ns));
            pw.println("123456789 and ! and # ");
            pw.flush();
        }
    }
```

the output is: OneTwoThreeFourFiveSixSevenEightNine 97110100 33 97110100 35 1310

can somebody please tell me how to format code easier in this forum?  I had to manually 8 space indent each line and there's got to be an easier way!

Comment: Use the tab key...  Also, most programming text editors will auto-indent the new line to where the last one started.

Comment: easiest way is to use an editor to format your code with spaces for indentation (no tabs) and an extra 4 spaces of indent on every line.  Then just cut-paste from the editor to SO input box.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For characters that aren't digits, you're taking the character code and converting it to a number.  So 97 110 and 100 are the character codes for 'a', 'n', and 'd' while 33 and 35 are `!` and `#`.

What you probably want for your default case is just:

```
default: sb.append((char)c); break;
```

Note that creating a new StringBuffer each time the write routine is called is extremely wasteful and inefficient.  Since you're only ever appending one string/char to it, you might as well just print that string/char directly rather than copying through a StringBuffer.

Comment: Hmmm, I tried that but it is still showing the same output.  I'm guessing it's automatically being converted to ascii when I pass the value in.  Is there something that converts ascii back to a character?

Answer (score 0):

You are outputing the ascii code of characters which are not digits in `sb.append(Integer.toString(c))`.